# Inappropriate argument value (of correct type). in JES (Python/Jython)

Tags: python, computer-science, jython, jes

Hey so I am just working on some coding homework for my Python class using JES. Our assignment is to take a sound, add some white noise to the background and to add an echo as well. There is a bit more exacts but I believe I am fine with that. There are four different functions that we are making: a main, an echo equation based on a user defined length of time and amount of echos, a white noise generation function, and a function to merge the noises.

Here is what I have so far, haven't started the merging or the main yet.

```
#put the following line at the top of your file. This will let
#you access the random module functions
import random

#White noise Generation functiton, requires a sound to match sound length
def whiteNoiseGenerator(baseSound) :
 noise = makeEmptySound(getLength(baseSound))
 index = 0  
 for index in range(0, getLength(baseSound)) :
  sample = random.randint(-500, 500)
  setSampleValueAt(noise, index, sample)
 return noise


def multipleEchoesGenerator(sound, delay, number) :
  endSound = getLength(sound)
  newEndSound = endSound +(delay * number)

  len = 1 + int(newEndSound/getSamplingRate(sound))
  newSound = makeEmptySound(len)

  echoAmplitude = 1.0
  for echoCount in range (1, number) :
    echoAmplitude = echoAmplitude * 0.60
    for posns1 in range (0, endSound):
    posns2 = posns1 + (delay * echoCount)
    values1 = getSampleValueAt(sound, posns1) * echoAmplitude
    values2 = getSampleValueAt(newSound, posns2)
    setSampleValueAt (newSound, posns2, values1 + values2)
return newSound
```

I receive this error whenever I try to load it in.

**The error was:**

```
Inappropriate argument value (of correct type).
An error occurred attempting to pass an argument to a function.
Please check line 38 of C:\Users\insanity180\Desktop\Work\Winter Sophomore\CS 140\homework3\homework_3.py
```

That line of code is:

```
setSampleValueAt (newSound, posns2, values1 + values2)
```

Anyone have an idea what might be happening here? Any assistance would be great since I am hoping to give myself plenty of time to finish coding this assignment. I have gotten a similar error before and it was usually a syntax error however I don't see any such errors here.

The sound is made before I run this program and I defined delay and number as values 1 and 3 respectively.

Comment: I am sorry I am confused by what you mean by that Antti. My assumption of setSampleValueAt is that it does get declared at all, and is more like the first function I linked that generates white noise. That was able to run without being defined (since it is changing the sample value per position in the sound). I am still pretty new to coding but I don't believe that it should be defined.

Answer (score 1):

Check the arguments to `setSampleValueAt`; your sample value must be out of bounds (should be within `-32768` - `32767`). You need to do some kind of output clamping for your algorithm.

Another possibility (which indeed **was the error**, according to further input) is that your echo will be out of the range of the sample - that is, if your sample was 5 seconds long, and echo was 0.5 seconds long; or the `posns1 + delay` is beyond the length of the sample; the length of the new sound is not calculated correctly.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by output clamping though I don't believe that is the error. Through some commenting out of parts I believe the error is with the posn2 part of the code though I am not sure why. When I define it I give it the value of posn1 (which should be an int) then add delay and echoCount. They are just numbers, nothing should be causing errors there. I even tried defining echoCount and giving it a value of 1 but that didn't do any good.

Comment: Also just noticed this is also coming up in the error message that I forgot to post."You are trying to access the sample at index: 6, but the last valid index is at 5"

Comment: I don't think that is the problem since when I define newEndSound I define it's length from the original sound, then I add to it the time of the delay times the number of echoes. That should be how long it is no?